# Assertion error trying to implement Drag and Drop with embedded JavaFX in Swing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I wrote code for a TableView that will allow rows to drag and drop. Works great as a standalone JavaFX application. However, it doesn't work in an embedded JFXPanel for work in a Swing app. I want to integrate it with my Swing app, so I can't use it as a standalone.

The error is in the JavaFX code itself, which isn't giving me a whole lot to go on. I'm not sure if I can alter my code to fix the problem.

I've cut out most of the rest of the code, and left the first part it fails on. The onDragDetected code fails first.

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at javafx.embed.swing.SwingDnD.startDrag(SwingDnD.java:261)
at javafx.embed.swing.SwingDnD.access$1000(SwingDnD.java:73)
at javafx.embed.swing.SwingDnD$4$1.run(SwingDnD.java:249)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
…
```

Here is my code that creates the handler in a customized TableView class

```
private EventHandler<MouseEvent> createDragDetectedHandler(
    final TableCell<ReportSelectedItem, String> cell) {
    return new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            try {

                Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(String.valueOf(cell.getIndex()));
                WritableImage snapshot = cell.getTableRow().snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
                db.setDragView(snapshot);
                db.setContent(content);
            } catch (AssertionError ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The exception is thrown from this line: `Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);`

I added in the try-catch blocks to narrow it down, and find that line. The stack trace is giant, so I didn't post all of it.

Here's the class declaration

```
public class DragAndDropTableCell<S extends Object, T extends Object> extends TableCell {

private ReportSelectedItem blankRSI = new ReportSelectedItem();

public DragAndDropTableCell() {
    super();
    setOnDragDetected(createDragDetectedHandler(this));

}
```

So, I noticed that it's calling SwingDnD in my embedded instance, but GlassScene in the stand alone. So it's using different code for the Drag and Drop functionality.

Is this a bug I should report to Oracle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a bug via JIRA to the JavaFX dev team. It looks like they accepted as a bug.

The workaround I found was to change:

`Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);`

to

`Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY_MOVE);`

I'm not sure how much that changes in internal functionality. But basic drag and drop seems to be working fine.